# Perl remove substring in the middle of a string

Tags: perl, replace

How can I remove (or replace by nothing) the 4th and 5th character of my string, in this case number 5 and number 6, to go from this:

```
123456789
```

to this:

```
1234789
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just replace it with [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

```
use 5.12;
my $foo = '123456789';
substr $foo, 4, 2, q{};

say $foo; # prints 1234789
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`substr()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) as lvalue

```
my $str = "123456789";
substr($str, 4, 2) = "";

print $str;
```

output

```
1234789
```

Comment: Note you need to have the parenthesis to do that because otherwise the `=` binds higher than the `substr` call and you end up with a warning because you are trying to assign the empty string to `2`.

Comment: Yeah that bit me nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) fuction:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "123456789";
substr($string, 4, 2, '');
print $string, "\n";
```

Output:

```
1234789
```